# Disabling generate html code in one-line in the Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I don't have idea how to config Nuxt 3 that this framework doesn't generate html code in one-line.

I've tried disable minify set on false etc. but didn't work.

Nuxt 3 working in SSR mode.

```
nuxt.config.js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    components: {
        global: true,
        dirs: ['~/components', "~/components/plugins"]
    },
    css: [
        'primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css',
        'primevue/resources/primevue.css',
        'primeicons/primeicons.css',
        'primeflex/primeflex.css',
        '~/public/global.css'
    ],
    runtimeConfig: {
        // The private keys which are only available within server-side
        apiBase: 'http://localhost:8080',
        replaceApiBase: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        // Keys within public, will be also exposed to the client-side
        public: {
            apiBase: 'http://localhost:8080',
            replaceApiBase: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
        }
    },
    vite: {
        optimizeDeps: {},
        build: {
        },
        minifyHTML: {
            collapseWhitespace: false
        }
    },
    build: {
        minify: false
    }
})
```

[image]

I would like that:

[image]

Thanks :)